# Normal sampling random rotations in SO(3) around the identity within a fixed geodesic distance as variance

Tags: lie-groups, rotations, random, sampling, geodesic

*Problem.* Assuming we have a fixed distance/variance $ \sigma^2 $, the problem I have, is to sample rotations $R \in SO\left(3\right) $ around the identity $ I $ with isotropic covariance given as $ \sigma^2 $.

*What I know.* I know, that the geodesic distance between two rotations is as follows:
$ d\left(R_1, R_2\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}||\log\left(R_1^TR_2\right)||_F $, where $ \log $ denotes the Logarithmic map $ \colon SO\left(3\right) \mapsto \mathfrak{so}\left(3\right)$. Furthermore I know how to compute the geodesic distance between the two quaternions. Fixing one of the rotations $ R_1 = I $, I can form a constraint for the parameters depending on my sampling variance. So far so good, but I know from generating random uniform samples for $ SO\left(3\right) $ that sampling can be tricky. Normal sampling the components of a quaternion and then normalizing, generates uniform samples. Random sampling Euler angles is more tricky, but doable when sampling from specific distributions according to an article from RE Miles in 1965. However, generating samples with these methods will cover the space of all rotations.

*Idea.* The first solution I see then, is that I could just sample repeatedly with these methods and then reject samples that lie outside of $ \mathbb{B}_\sigma $ by checking the geodesic distance. I then just repeat this, until enough samples are collected. But since I want a normal distribution, wouldn't that mean, that only most rotations lie inside the ball and some can be outside of it? I would have to carefully reject, to still have the normal distribution. Furthermore, the method is not very efficient.

If I were to stay in $ T_IM $ and sample in the space of skew-symmetric matrices, how would I proceed? I like to think that the problem can be solved for $ w $, with $ R = \exp \hat{w} $. If I sample the components of the angular velocity $ w $ and then map back to the group, how can I know the distribution of the rotations?

I am unsure on how to sample, so that the geodesic distances compared to the identity are following a specific distribution. I would be thankful for any help or advice!

Comment: At the top you say you want to sample uniformly. Then in the third paragraph you say you want a normal distribution. (Presumably you mean a truncated normal distribution?) Which one is right?

Comment: You are right! I confused these, because in order to generate uniform random rotations, I sample each component of a quaternion from a normal distribution. However, in this case I am only interested in normal distributed rotations around the identity, because I want to use these as noise with specific variance.

Comment: I don't understand. You sample the components of quaternions from a normal distribution to generate uniform random rotations? I don't see how that could work. Are we talking about Haar-measure uniform, or are you using some other measure?

Comment: Well this is not part of the question per se, but given the entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Uniform_random_rotation_matrices it is possible in regards to the Haar-measure I believe. I mentioned this, because I stumbled upon this problem some other time before and realized, that it's not trivial. That's what makes me wonder, if my rotations will distributed correctly after sampling.

Comment: Ok, I found an answer to this ill-posed question by now. Sampling the components of the infinitesimal rotations and an angle from a normal distribution, will result in the correct half-normal distribution of distances from the rotations. Seems like a stupid question now in retrospective, sorry!

Comment: You might be interested in cubochoric sampling http://muri.materials.cmu.edu/?p=69. Happy to direct you to some implementations if of interest.